# Git copy contents of one branch into another

Tags: git, github, github-actions

So I know there are multiple answers to this problem but they all don't work. I simply want the git commands to copy the files from one branch into another. Unfortunately, when I want to merge the two branches, it either gives me the error that there isn't a relation (which makes sense but still I don't care I just want to have the current state of the files of the one branch to the other) or it says nothing to commit tree clean.

It can't be that hard to just copy the current state of the files of branch a to branch b right?

EDIT: Yes, the history doesn't matter, I just want the current code state to be on the new branch, maybe with a new commit

Comment: So you are trying to delete branch B entirely and replace it with A?

Comment: Not delete but put the current state of branch A into branch B and ignore the old states of branch B

Comment: Since the contents of branch B is ignored, you are basically deleting it, right? Or do you want to keep some data from B

Comment: yeah and no, it's like deleting the branch and recreating it with the current state of branch A

Comment: It’s not that it’s hard. It’s that your goal is unclear. If you want two branches to share an existing history then just start a new branch at the end of the old branch.

Comment: As I mentioned, I just want it to be like I copied the files from folder A to folder B and replace them, it should just replace all the files on branch B with the files from branch A, I don't really care about the history other than that I want to be able to go back to a old state because it gives security

Answer (score 1):

## Option One

So what you want to do is delete B and create a new branch with the same name:

```
git branch -d B
```

Note: All data on B will be permanently destroyed. It might be better to rename B like this:

```
git branch -m B B_old
```

Now, you can create a new branch `B` branching of of A:

```
git checkout A
git switch -c B
```

Now the branch B will be exactly the same as A (including history)

## Option Two

You can also use the `theirs` option to resolve all merge conflicts from the remote branch:

```
git switch B
git merge A -s theirs
```

This will use the changes from A whenever there is a conflict, but keep changes from B if there is not. This only works if branches A and B have a common ancestor somewhere.

Comment: That is great, but I still want to keep the history maybe.. If there is no other option I will have to delete it, but it's meant to be a release branch with a minified version of the code for my server to download and it might cause issues if the branch is getting deleted while clients are on this branch, right?

Comment: It might be a problem once because of the unrelated histories. After that you can simply use `git merge --theirs` to merge everything